# it takes wrong project name while running maven /java project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have projectname tasknew but when i run it ,it takes springmvcjava in url and works perfectlly,

complete url is

```
 localhost:8080/SpringMVCjava
```

but at a same time **my project name** is **tasknew**..what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

go to your server(tomcat server project) project,which refers to tomcat..
then in server.xml file

edit path..in path attribute as i mentioned below

```
 <Context docBase="tasknew" path="/tasknew" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:tasknew"/></Host>
```

I have to change path in path attribute..i have corrected the path name as `/tasknew` and it works fine.